# Why does this program loop forever?

Tags: c, loops, infinite-loop, cs50

The goal of the program is to perform a checksum in the following way: multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together.
Add the sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2. If the total modulo 10 is 0, the number is valid The problem with my code is that it runs forever, therefore I suppose something is wrong with the loops, any suggestion on why that might be happening and how to fix it? Note:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <math.h>

double input(void);

int main(void)
{
    double number = input();
    double sum = 0;
    double i = 1;
    double current_digit;
    do
    {
        current_digit = (fmod(number, pow(10,i)) - fmod(number, pow(10, i-1)))/pow(10, i-1); //formula to calculate the ith digit in a number
        if (fmod(i,2) != 0)
        {
            sum += current_digit;
        }
        else
        {
            double second_number = 2*current_digit;
            double j = 1;
            do
            {
                double second_current_digit = (fmod(second_number, pow(10,j)) -fmod(second_number,pow(10, j-1)))/pow(10, j-1);
                sum += second_current_digit;
                j++;
            }
            while (fmod(second_number, pow(10,j)) == number);
        i++;
        }
    }
    while (fmod(number,pow(10, i)) != number);
    if (fmod(sum,10) == 0)
    {
        printf("true");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("false");
    }
}

double input(void)
{
    double number = get_double("Number: ");
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a debugger to step through the execution and follow the changes to `number`? If that's not available somehow, did you add instructions to print some text for you to track what happened ex-post-facto? We're not a debugging service... also, exact comparison of floating-point values is always suspect. Perhaps there's a very slight difference that your missing? Finally, why use floating-point values when you care about exact representation?

Comment: `pow(10, i)` is not guaranteed to produce `1000...0000`, may instead give stuff like `999...999.997653213`

Comment: @einpoklum If by floating point usage you mean the usage of double, the program will have to take in 16 digits or even more, I didn't know what to do to handle larger integers, maybe long type? Anyway, thank you for the printing hint, I'll try

Comment: @pmg Might I be supposed to round to solve this?

Comment: Don't use math's library `pow()`. Write your own `long unsigned integer_pow(unsigned base, unsigned exp) { long unsigned v = 1; while (exp--) v *= base; return v; }`

Comment: @pmg ty, should I also convert the rest to long?

Comment: In your program, yes. If you don't want to deal with the mess of floating-point values, use **integers** (`int`, `long unsigned`, ...) all over (and get rid of the `<math.h>` inclusion).

Answer (score 1):

> the usage of double ... the program will have to take in 16 digits or even more, I didn't know what to do to handle larger integers, maybe long type?

Most computers these days support 64-bit integers natively. Those can give you as many as floor(log_10(2^64)) = 19 decimal digits. If that's sufficient, use `uint64_t` from `<stdint.h>` (it's a type defined in the C standard).

If that's not sufficient, consider using an array of digits, or a more involved "big integer" data type, as in [here](https://gist.github.com/bloopletech/338338).

Anyway, I'm betting the exact floating-point comparison is what's biting you, as, probably, the value of `pow(10,i)` is not an exact power of 10, so the `fmod()` changes `number` slightly. But - don't trust my guess, just use a debugger:

- In a terminal: [How to Debug C Program using gdb in 6 Simple Steps](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/), or
- In a graphic IDE: For example, [Debugging C using Visual Studio Code on Linux](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BYRoxIYP04M).